# Automatically fill title attribute of image

Tags: media

I defined a content type that consists of a field photo for which I can add up to 20 photos. I'm using the [Multiupload Imagefield Widget](https://drupal.org/project/multiupload_imagefield_widget) module to be able to upload several images to one node. Since I'm using descriptive filenames, I would like the title attribute of each image to be automatically filled (instead of filling them all by myself). Does anybody know how to do this?

I looked at the File entity module, but this creates individual pieces of content for each Image I upload. That is not the direction I want to go in.

UPDATE: I'm using D7

Comment: AgA: The descriptive filename is shown nowhere. I would like to use the descriptive filename in the title attribute of the Image.

Answer (score 0):

If you use D6 try image_fupload module.

> Automatic node title creation and predefining of imagefield fields (customisable / themeable / editable by user / token support [imagefield])

Comment: I updated my question: I'm using D7